# It showing wrong output ? Whats wrong with this code

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to run this simple javascript code but doesn't get desired output. This code showing "You are pass" instead of "You are fail". Please tell where im wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      If else if and else use
    </title>
  </head>
<body>
  <script>
  function ifelseifelse() {
  var marks=32;
  if (marks>33){
  alert("You are Pass");
  }
  else if(marks=33)
  {
  alert("You are pass");
  }
  else{
  alert("You are fail");
  }

  }
  </script>
  <button type = "button" onclick="ifelseifelse()" >If else-if if</button> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (marks=33)`  this is assignment. `if (marks === 33)` this is comparison.

Comment: And of course, if 33 or higher means a pass, you don't need two conditions for it: `if (marks >= 33)`...

Comment: @dfsq Thanks solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
else if(marks=33)
```

instead of

```
else if(marks==33)
```

You are assigning 33 to `marks` instead of comparing it

Answer (score 0):

Use == in the else-if to compare your marks with 33

Answer (score 0):

it's getting hung up at the second statement.

if(marks=33) should be if(marks === 33)